# Catching MySQL errors

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple development. I was using Pear DB to error catch a query with something along the lines of

```
if(DB::isError($create)) die($create->getMessage());
```

I'm wondering if there is something similar in mysql?

Comment: You mean within the mysql command line itself? If so, yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pear DB is Database Abstraction Layer which works with MySQL.

MySQL:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_error()) { die('error!:' . mysql_error() ); }
```

Comment: Obviously he wants to display the error, so in his case: `$result = mysql_query($query); if(mysql_error()) die(mysql_error());`

Comment: yes I want to display the error - and (sorry for being dense) I don't need to pass $result into the argument? ... just mysql_error()

Comment: no you don't. mysql_error() takes one optional argument - connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```